# Get CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC with one call

Tags: posix, timestamp

I can use

```
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);
```

to get CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC which one call each.

Is it possible to get *both* with *one* call so the result is the kernel's best guess what both are at the time I'm requesting it?

**Background:** I need to sync the two to spot jumps in CLOCK_REALTIME which is synced to GPS time and I fear (don't know if that's a valid fear) that calling clock_gettime() twice will add to my problems because a lot might happen between my two calls.

Comment: I exactly want to see those significantly different values; I need to tag measurement data with timestamps, but if the measurement starts at a location where GPS is not available, I want to spot the adjustments done later to reorder data. Also, after e.g. a long tunnel, CLOCK_REALTIME might jump while CLOCK_MONOTONIC won't.

Comment: @StephenKitt *I’m still curious about what the output would look like* `54:3234:3752 APM`?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I want to have a value at call point A telling me that MONOTONIC is 1000, while REALTIME is 1000000. Next call, I want to see that MONOTONIC is now 1005, and REALTIME is 1000006, so I can see both what the system internally thinks the time is and that I can spot any smearing or jumps. I want to tag data with both timestamps so that even if I'm not always able to compensate, I can at least see it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get *both* with *one* call so the result is the kernel's best guess what both are at the time I'm requesting it?

No, it isn’t; [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) only supports a single clock identifier, and can only populate a single `struct timespec`. POSIX doesn’t define a “best guess” synthetic clock either.

You can determine an upper bound on the time difference between the monotonic and realtime clocks by calling `clock_gettime` three times: retrieve the monotonic time, then the wall-clock time, then the monotonic time again. This would also work to ensure relative ordering on timestamps; keeping all three should allow you to make sense of wall-clock time jumps.

If you’re targeting Linux, you may want to use [`CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` or `CLOCK_BOOTTIME`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html); the former is a monotonic clock which isn’t affected by incremental adjustments made by `adjtime` or NTP, and the latter additionally isn’t affected by time spent suspended.